# Internet security

Tags: 14.04

I have Ubuntu running parallel with Windows on my hard disc. The windows has Norton 360, can I use a different antivirus on the Ubuntu section without creating problems?

Comment: Yes, you can..before that [read this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and you can do it, but for the most part, all linux OS'es are safe from viruses so it shouldn't  really be necessary unless you use a virtual machine like wine